# Proof of a step in the proof of $\text{ad}(X)(Y)=[X,Y]$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

In case different notations are used in different places, let me define everything here. Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algebra. Without specifying otherwise, a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is to be understood as the tangent space of $G$ at identity. Denoted as $\mathfrak{g}=T_eG$, but occasionally we also understand it as the set of all left-invariant vector fields on $G$, in which case we use $l(X)$ to denote a left invariant vector field that takes value $X$ at identity.

Define function $Ad(g)$ for every $g\in G$ by
\begin{align}
&Ad(g):\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}\\&Ad(g)(X):=d_eI_gX
\end{align}
where function $I_g:G\to G$ is the inner automorphism on G, i.e. $I_g(h)=ghg^{-1}$. And differential $d_eI_g:T_eG\to T_eG$ acts by the rule
\begin{equation}
d_eI_gX(f):=X(f\circ I_g)
\end{equation}
Define map $ad:\mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{g}\to (T_{Y}\mathfrak{g}\cong\mathfrak{g})$ by \begin{equation}
ad(X)(Y):=d_eAd(.)(Y)X
\end{equation}
where $Ad(.)(Y):G\to \mathfrak{g}$ is understood as a map between Lie group $G$ and smooth manifold $\mathfrak{g}$. I am hoping to prove the following identity which states
\begin{equation}
ad(X)(Y)=\frac{\partial(Ad(e^{tl(X)})(Y))}{\partial t}|_{t=0}
\end{equation}
where $e^{tl(X)}$ denotes a curve on $G$, denoted $\gamma^{l(X)}_e(t)$ with the property that

1. $\gamma^{l(X)}_e(0)=e\in G$
2. it is the unique curve that $\frac{d\gamma^{l(X)}}{d t}f:=\frac{\partial f(\gamma^{l(X)}_e(t))}{\partial t}=l(X)_{\gamma^{l(X)}_e(t)}f$

Comment: Is that not just the chain rule? You are aware of the fact that the very last expression on the right hand side of 2. is (at $t=0$) just $Xf$?

Comment: Hi, yes. But I am asking about $ad(X)(Y)$ which is the line before the 1. and 2. points. I can't see how chain rule applied to that one.

Comment: I am not sure if you are hinting that I could use point 2 in the last line to prove $ad(X)(Y)$ equality. If you are, I am sorry but I really cannot make a connection on how to apply chain rule to it, could you please specify.

Comment: Oh my, so I have to $\LaTeX$ this stuff...My naive thinking is that the chain rule should tell you that
$$\left. \frac{\partial(Ad(e^{tl(X))})(Y)}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0} = \left.d_{e^{tl(X))}} Ad(.)(Y)\frac{d}{dt}\gamma_e^{l(X)}(t) \right|_{t=0}= 
d_{e} Ad(.)(Y)X$$